# "Eines oft nicht sind: wirklich gesund" meaning?

Tags: meaning, subject

> Das Coronavirus geht wohl an kaum jemandem spurlos vorbei - so oder so. Eine neue Studie legt nun allerdings nahe, dass selbst diejenigen, die eine Infektion überstanden haben und danach als offiziell genesen gelten, eines oft nicht sind: wirklich gesund.

What's the meaning of "*eines oft nicht sind: wirklich gesund*"? What's the subject word for '*sind*'?

Comment: @mic, no, and that’s one reason that answers in comments are bad.

Comment: @Carsten - You are right, but now, why did I come to think it was "eines", weird. On the other hand, a wrong answer does not deserve a place where it conquers with other answers. So, in my eyes it shows that comments are the only right place for it.

Comment: @mic  Consider deleting your comment with the misleading answer?

Comment: @mic, answers can be downvoted, comments not. Btw, you can delete your own comment s ;)

Comment: @mic: Rest assured, that wrong answers are downvoted quickly enough here to give some incentive for deletion. I removed the wrong comment.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side and to leave a comment where it isn't an answer linguistically: Covid-19 may leave long lasting or even permanent damage on patients, primarily to organs. The text does/should not imply that the assessment of their condition as 'being cured from Covid-19'  was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy I would suggest is the following: If the finite verb is in final position, go left until you find the beginning of the sentence, which must be a subordinating conjunction or a relative pronoun or similar, i.e. some word that can introduce a subordinate clause.

> **dass** selbst diejenigen, *die eine Infektion überstanden haben und danach als offiziell genesen gelten*, eines oft nicht **sind**

Then remove any extraneous parts, which in this case includes a long relative clause that I have marked in italics.

> `dass die(jenigen) eines     nicht sind`
> `that they         one thing not   are`
> *that there's one thing they are not*

This makes it easy to see that the subject is *die(jenigen)*.

Comment: I used code formatting to align the sentence with its gloss. The alternative would have been using a table.

Comment: I see. That's clear. My internet dictionary doesn't show eines. Why is it eines? This is normative singluar of ein?

Comment: @ChanKim It's the neuter singular of the [pronoun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/einer#Pronoun) (not the article) *ein*. The masculine form of the pronoun is used for persons *da kommt schon wieder **einer*** (*here comes another one*, *einer* = *ein Mann*), the neuter for things ***eines** sollte man nicht vergessen* (*one thing should not be forgot*, *eines/eins* = *eine Sache*).

Comment: Ah, das ist klar! danke!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence at the bottom of it is:

> Sie sind nicht wirklich gesund.

The *sie* refers to *dienjenigen*, i.e. to *those who recovered from Covid-19*.

The sentence in its entirety is syntactically correct but of course rather twisted, so I am not surprised you find it difficult. Translated it would be:

> A new study suggests that even those who recovered from infection and are officially considered recovered often in fact are one thing not: truly healthy.

The sentence sounds in German as manneristic as in English. Or in order to keep up the style: The sentence sounds in both languages nothing but one: manneristic.

Comment: @infinitezero   Okay, if you say so... I change it. Kind regards.

Comment: hi! thank you . ist diejenigen normative or dative? It looks like dative because of -en to me. and because the real subject is eines, shouldn't it be dative? (to those..) again because I don't have a good dictionary..

Comment: @ChanKim  *Diejenigen* is nominative. Here are all forms: Wer? Diejenigen - Wem? Denjenigen - Wessen? Derjenigen - Wen? Diejenigen. That's all plural of course. Singular forms are: Wer? Derjenige (diejenige, dasjenige) - Wem? Demjenigen (derjenigen, demjenigen) - Wessen? Desjenigen (derjenigen, desjenigen) - Wen? Denjenigen (diejenige, dasjenige). - I am sorry, I know this is totally confusing, and I would not like to be forced to learn it as a second language.

Comment: Geiselman I see. I think I can understand(and memorize) the derjenigen changes. Thank you for the kind explanation!

Answer (score 1):

subject is "diejenigen"

**diejenigen**
*[die eine Infektion überstanden haben und danach als offiziell genesen gelten]*
**eines oft nicht sind**: wirklich gesund.